# Hololens with Photon Voice 2 in Unity 2018.2.13

Tags: unity-game-engine, microphone, voice, hololens, photon

I have an issue with Photon Voice 2 on Hololens. I have a Unity 2017.4.13 application that runs Photon Voice 2 fine on device.

However when migrated to Unity 2018.2.13 it fails to start the Microphone using `Microphone.Start` I was able to get around this error by passing an empty string as microphone type which Unity documentation suggests will use the default microphone but then I get an exception on device.

```
Unable to load DLL webrtc-audio: The specific module could not be found
```

Has anyone else had Microphone issues in Unity 2018 or with Photon Voice 2 in general?

I should add i'm using IL2CPP for the scripting backend and Microphone permission are enabled in build settings. Also to clarify this works without error when built from Unity 2017.4.13.

Microphone.Start is called in the MicWrapper script within the Photon Voice 2 library.

```
public MicWrapper(string device, int suggestedFrequency)
        {
            if (Microphone.devices.Length < 1)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.device = device;
            int minFreq;
            int maxFreq;
            Microphone.GetDeviceCaps(device, out minFreq, out maxFreq);
            var frequency = suggestedFrequency;
            //        minFreq = maxFreq = 44100; // test like android client
            if (suggestedFrequency < minFreq || maxFreq != 0 && suggestedFrequency > maxFreq)
            {
                Debug.LogWarningFormat("[PV] MicWrapper does not support suggested frequency {0} (min: {1}, max: {2}). Setting to {2}",
                    suggestedFrequency, minFreq, maxFreq);
                frequency = maxFreq;
            }
            this.mic = Microphone.Start(device, true, 1, frequency);
        }
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: There's no code to post. This is either a configuration, platform, permissions or library issue.

Comment: The call to Microphone.Start is inside the Photon Voice 2 Unity library

Comment: `I was able to get around this error by passing an empty string as microphone type` how did you pass it? configuration?

Comment: I edited the MicWrapper script directly replacing the device with an empty string.

Comment: Update: I now think the exception thrown on device is a red herring as I now have the 2017 version also throwing the error with Photon Voice 2 still working and transmitting voice from the hololens.

Comment: Hi @Paul, thank you for choosing Photon! The exception is probably due to the WebRTC DSP component ("VoiceAudioPreprocessor") not being able to load the DLL (webrtc-audio.dll) for the respective platform target/build config.